# OpenLayers bindTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm getting this error message when I try to bind view of the first map to the second map. So, I have two maps - mapOne and mapTwo. When I do not make any binding they are working nicely. However, when I slightly change declaration of mapTwo and add binding statement, I get that error message. This is a code I have.

```
// Before. It works good.
var mapTwo = new ol.Map({
    target: obj,
    renderer: 'canvas',
    layers: layers,
    controls:[],
    view: view
});

//After. It does not work
var mapTwo = new ol.Map({
    target: obj,
    renderer: 'canvas',
    layers: layers,
    controls:[]
});

mapTwo.bindTo('view', mapOne);
```

So, what am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Hmmm. I checked OpenLayers 3 api - http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html. And it is rather interesting. Where has `bindTo` method disappeared??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bindTo` was removed in v3.5.0. See the [release notes](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0):

"If you want to get notification about ol.Object property changes, you can listen for the 'propertychange' event (e.g. object.on('propertychange', listener)). Two-way binding can be set up at the application level using property change listeners. See [#3472](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3472) for details on the change."